# Is hiding your voice on phone legal?

Tags: united-states, legal, phone

Lets say I use a computer to change my voices pitch, or use computer generated voices to hit a repeater. Is this allowed, or does it have to be my natural voice coming in on phone transmissions?

I am in the United States of America.

Comment: Everyone on SSB is using a pitch changer, in a sense...

Comment: It would be helpful to have information about your locale.

Comment: @DavidVK2VXK That's why the question was put on hold. "Is X legal?" is almost by definition unanswerable without knowledge of the legislative area being discussed. Each such question should state the relevant location; readers should not have to search for information that belongs in the question.

Comment: i guess ill just do it assuming its legal :)

Comment: they cant get too mad

Comment: So you're going to identify with your callsign, which tells people your name and address, but you want to disguise your voice?

Comment: The transmission of all sorts of funny tones is allowed (Packet, FSK, JT65).  The transmission of robotic voice repeater identifiers is allowed.  I would think the use of a computerized voice as an aid to the disabled would be allowed.  FCC Rules Part 97.113 lists prohibited transmissions.  Prohibited by paragraph (4) includes "communications intended to facilitate a
criminal act", "messages encoded for the purpose of obscuring their meaning, except as otherwise provided herein (e.g. control of a repeater or satellite)" and   "false or deceptive messages, signals or identification."

Answer (score 4):

Nowhere in FCC Part 97 does it specify you have to use *your* natural voice.  And, as many commenters have noted, there are lots of places where you don't.  I will add to that list:

- I am the control operator for an unlicensed (or lower class) user
- Anyone other than the trustee operating a club station.
- Using my XYL's voice to record CQ macros for contesting ;)

The key is that the control operator is identified in accordance with FCC rules and since that licensee's identity is clearly known from the ULS database, there's no attempt to really hide from anyone who cares enough to look you up.